# PHP Mysql I have four rows in my table 1234 but i just want to show 123 rows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have four rows in my table 1234 but i just want to show 123 rows or like i have N rows and i want to show N-1 rows in php Mysql query. Please help me to solve it.
thanx in advance

Comment: This question is so wrong in multiple ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "LIMIT" to get that count of row as you want.

Edit.

This "LIMIT" you use in SQL. http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm

Comment: but i have random rows with many entries and i just want to skip the last row. these rows are dynamic rows

Comment: When you get rows from database you use "LIMIT" in SQL and you can get as much as rows as you want. If you dont know how many record you have, first you can get all recrods see how many there are and remove from this numer "1" and now you get N-1.

Answer (score 0):

use mysql clause limit joined to query

ex:

```
select * from extable limit 30
```

Comment: for suppose you have 40 columns in table A.still if you want to get only 5 of them then query will be ex:-
select * from a limit 5;